# How to configure webpack-dev-server to listen to random port that heroku assigns on deployment?

Tags: node.js, heroku, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

How to configure webpack-dev-server to listen to random port that heroku assigns on deployment of a React based web-application?

Comment: Can you try running webpack-dev-server through Node? Assuming Heroku sets some env variables, you could do the necessary configuration tweaks there. webpack-dev-server hasn't been designed for this sort of usage, though, and the docs advise against it, but I guess you know what you are doing.